# Resize QPaint drawRect by dragging the corner in order to select the ImageCrop Area

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want the red rectangle resize like this

[image]

now

[image]

I would like to keep Image remain the same size, but resize the Red Rectangle by dragging the corner of Red Rectangle, **icon displayed at the same time**.

I reimplement QLabel to repaint the image and rectangle, but how can I reposition the icon at the corner?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, QSize, QRectF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CropLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CropLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.img = None
        self.left_top = QPointF(0, 0)
        self.bot_right = QPointF(0, 0)
        self.left_top_icon = QPixmap('images/lefttop-botright.png').scaled(QSize(25, 25))

    def setPixmap(self, QPixmap):
        self.img = QPixmap
        h, w = QPixmap.height(), QPixmap.width()
        self.bot_right = QPointF(self.left_top.x() + w, self.left_top.y() + h)
        self.resize(QSize(w, h))


    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        if self.img is not None:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.drawPixmap(self.left_top, self.img)
            painter.drawPixmap(self.left_top.x() - self.left_top_icon.width() / 2,
                               self.left_top.y() - self.left_top_icon.height() / 2,
                               self.left_top_icon)

            paintRect = QPen(Qt.red)
            paintRect.setWidth(3)
            painter.setPen(paintRect)
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.left_top, self.bot_right))

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.label = CropLabel(self)
        self.board_width = 100
        qPixmap = QPixmap('images/cat.jpg')
        self.resize(QSize(qPixmap.width() + self.board_width * 2, qPixmap.height() + self.board_width * 2))
        self.label.left_top = QPointF   (self.board_width, self.board_width)
        self.label.setPixmap(qPixmap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the cursor position and then update the widget to repaint it.

QLabel, like most widgets, usually receives mouseMoveEvens only if a mouse button is being clicked, but you might want to check against it if you are going to implement `mouseTracking` (which emits that event everytime the mouse moves over the widget).

```
class CropLabel(QLabel):
    # ...
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # update the mouse position and refresh the contents, only if the a
        # mouse button is pressed
        if event.buttons():
            self.left_top = event.pos()
            self.update()

    # do NOT use "QPaintEvent" as argument name, as it's an object class name
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.img is not None:
            rect = QRectF(self.left_top, self.bot_right)
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            # save the painter state
            painter.save()
            # set a clip rectangle (the image will not be drawn outside)
            painter.setClipRect(rect)
            painter.drawPixmap(self.left_top, self.img)
            # restore the previous painter state
            painter.restore()
            painter.drawPixmap(self.left_top.x() - self.left_top_icon.width() / 2,
                               self.left_top.y() - self.left_top_icon.height() / 2,
                               self.left_top_icon)

            paintRect = QPen(Qt.red)
            paintRect.setWidth(3)
            painter.setPen(paintRect)
            painter.drawRect(rect)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # set a layout and add the label to it, otherwise it will have a
        # fixed size which will probably be smaller than the window
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = CropLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        # ...
```

Please note that this whole approach is very basic (for example, the resizing happens even if the user clicks outside the "arrow" cursor), and using this kind of interaction for what you're probably going to achieve is not suggested. You will probably want to have a look at the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which requires some understanding and studying but is much more recommended for this kind of things.

Comment: Can the resizing happens only when the user clicks on the "corner"(specific position) and the "arrow"(any icon) displayed at the "resizing mode" by "Graphics View Framework" ?

Comment: @Jiburiru it can happen in any way, it depends on how you reimplement it. If you are really going to use a graphics view, I suggest to read the documentation carefully, look for some tutorials, and do *a lot* of experiments.